# Performance of Observable Data Service in Angular/NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am working on a NativeScript/Angular app that allows users to navigate a hierarchy of folders.  Due to the way NativeScript uses native views, I have created odd-folder and even-folder components that are alternated as the user moves through the hierarchy.  Both components share the same template.  The template has an *ngFor async pipe pointing to an Observable array.  In ngOnInit of each component I make a service call that returns an observable array of the folder contents for the currently visible folder.

Overall this approach works well and does what I want.

However, In the process of adding functionality I changed my data service to have a single BehaviorSubject that each service call pushes the contents array onto so that I can update the view if the folder contents are modified by a background process.

After I made this conversion I noticed that the performance of my app got dramatically worse, with several second delays between screens.  It seems to get slower as I navigate around, but it's hard to quantify

I am not sure what if anything I am doing wrong.

Enough talk, on to the code. (these are excepts showing the relevant code only)

**Service Code**

```
private _matrixItemList: BehaviorSubject<MatrixItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

get matrixItems() {
    return this._matrixItemList.asObservable();
}

public listFolderContents(folder: Folder) {

    return this.matrixItemRepository.getFolderContents(folder)
      .then(folderContents => {
        this._matrixItemList.next(folderContents);
      });
}


public listFolderContentsAsObservable(folder: Folder): Observable<MatrixItem[]> {

    return Observable.fromPromise(this.matrixItemRepository.getFolderContents(folder));

}
```

**Folder Component Template**

```
<StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="matrix-item" *ngFor="let matrixItem of matrixItems | async" (tap)="viewMatrixItem($event, matrixItem)">
            <ng-container *ngIf="matrixItem.type === 'folder'; then folderBlock else photoBlock"></ng-container>
            <ng-template #folderBlock>
                <matrix-folder [folder]="matrixItem"></matrix-folder>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template #photoBlock>
                <matrix-photo [photo]="matrixItem"></matrix-photo>
            </ng-template>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

**Folder Component Using BehaviorSubject [SLOW]**

```
    ngOnInit() {

        this.matrixItems = this.matrixItemService.matrixItems;

        this.matrixItemCountSubscription = this.matrixItems
          .subscribe(
          matrixItems => {
            this.matrixItemCount = matrixItems.length;
          },
          (error) => {

            console.log("FolderOddComponent - ERROR getting matrixItems");
            console.dir(error);

          });

       this.matrixItemService.listFolderContents(folder);
      });
  }


private onPageUnloaded(eventData) {

    if (this.matrixItemCountSubscription != null) {
      this.matrixItemCountSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

**Folder Component Using Observable [FAST]**

```
    ngOnInit() {

        this.matrixItems = this.matrixItemService.listFolderContentsAsObservable(folder);

        this.matrixItemCountSubscription = this.matrixItems
          .subscribe(
          matrixItems => {
            this.matrixItemCount = matrixItems.length;
          },
          (error) => {

            console.log("FolderOddComponent - ERROR getting matrixItems");
            console.dir(error);

          });

      });
  }

private onPageUnloaded(eventData) {

    if (this.matrixItemCountSubscription != null) {
      this.matrixItemCountSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

Comment: it doesn't works

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: I would recommend trying to change your `matrix-photo` and `matrix-folder` components to an `OnPush` ChangeDetection strategy if you haven't already. that can help with performance greatly.